# How to concatenate the values based on other field in unix

Tags: unix, awk, group-concat

I have detail.txt file ,which contains

```
cat >detail.txt
Student ID,Student Name, Percentage
101,A,75
102,B,77            
103,C,34             
104,D,42        
105,E,75            
106,F,42          
107,G,77
```

1.I want to print concatenated output based on Percentage (group by Percentage) and print student name in single line separated by comma(,).
**Expected Output:**

```
75-A,E  
77-B,G  
42-D,F  
34-C
```

For above question i got that how can achieve this for 75 or 77 or 42. But i did not get how to write a code grouping third field (Percentage). 
I tried below code

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=",";if($3=="75") print $2}' detail.txt
```

2. I want to get output based on grading system which is given below.

```
marks < 45=THIRD  
marks>=45 and marks<60 =SECOND  
 marks>=60 and marks<=75 =FIRST  
marks>75 =DIST
```

**Expected Output:**

```
DIST:B,G  
FIRST:A,E  
THIRD:C,D,F
```

Please help me to get the expected output. Thank You..

Comment: you have posted 2 expected outputs: which one is final (or more important)?

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F, 'NR>1{ 
             if ($3<45) k="THIRD"; else if ($3>=45 && $3<60) k="SECOND";
             else if ($3>=60 && $3<=75) k="FIRST"; else k="DIST";
             a[k] = a[k]? a[k]","$2 : $2; 
         }END{ for(i in a) print i":"a[i] }' detail.txt
```

- `k` - variable that will be assigned with *"grading system"* name according to one of the `if (...) <exp>; else if(...) <exp> ...` statements
- `a[k]` - array `a` is indexed by determined *"grading system"* name `k`
- `a[k] = a[k]? a[k]","$2 : $2` - all "student names"(presented by the 2nd field `$2`) are accumulated/grouped into the needed *"grading system"*

---

The output:

```
DIST:B,G
THIRD:C,D,F
FIRST:A,E
```

Comment: Dear Roman, Thanks for your response. I am using putty (Kornshell), there I am getting "Syntax error at line 1" error message. Please suggest me to get this in Kornshell what changes I have to do.        Thank you..

Comment: @jhulan, hello, can you share a screenshot showing the command execution with error?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the following awk one-liner should do:

```
awk -F, '{a[$3]=a[$3] (a[$3] ? "," : "") $2} END {for(i in a) printf "%s-%s\n", i, a[i]}' input.txt
```

The second question can work almost the same way, storing your mark divisions in an array, then stepping through that array to determine the subscript for a new array:

```
BEGIN { FS=","; m[0]="THIRD"; m[45]="SECOND"; m[60]="FIRST"; m[75]="DIST" } { for (i=0;i<=100;i++) if ((i in m) && $3 > i) mdiv=m[i]; marks[mdiv]=marks[mdiv] (marks[mdiv] ? "," : "") $2 } END { for(i in marks) printf "%s:%s\n", i, marks[i] }
```

But this is unreadable. When you need this level of complexity, you're past the point of a one-liner. :)

So .. combining the two and breaking them out for easier reading (and commenting) we get the following:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=","
  m[0]="THIRD"
  m[45]="SECOND"
  m[60]="FIRST"
  m[75]="DIST"
}

{

  a[$3]=a[$3] (a[$3] ? "," : "") $2  # Build an array with percentage as the index

  for (i=0;i<=100;i++)                 # Walk through the possible marks
    if ((i in m) && $3 > i) mdiv=m[i]  # selecting the correct divider on the way
  marks[mdiv]=marks[mdiv] (marks[mdiv] ? "," : "") $2
                                       # then build another array with divider
                                       # as the index
}

END {                                # Once we've processed all the input,

  for(i in a)                        # step through the array,
    printf "%s-%s\n", i, a[i]        # printing the results.

  print "----"

  for(i in marks)                    # step through the array,
    printf "%s:%s\n", i, marks[i]    # printing the results.

}
```

You may be wondering why we `for (i=0;i<=100;i++)` instead of simply using `for (i in m)`. This is because awk does not guarantee the order of array elements, and when stepping through the `m` array, it's important that we see the keys in increasing order.

Comment: Thanks Ghoti for your response ,I am using putty (Kornshell), there I am getting "Syntax error at line 1" error message. Please suggest me to get this in Kornshell what changes I have to do. Thank you.

Comment: @jhulan, your choice of terminal software or shell should not affect the processing of the script. That error would seem to come from `awk`, so it's possible there's a copy-paste error. The one-liner works for me using both BSD and GNU awk. Why don't you try putting the "expanded" version into a file, then run it with `awk -f script.awk input.txt` ? Then, if there's still a syntax error, you'll see more precisely where it is. Also, what version of awk are you using? (Try running `awk --version`.) Please update your question with any of these details, so other answers may be improved as well.

Comment: @jhulan Also, I've expanded my answer to address your second example output. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I am using Solaris , here i am able to create an array using `set -A arary_name values` .So i tried with `set -A marks `sed -e "1d" details.txt|awk -F"," '{printf $3","}`    . I can store values in array marks, but simple for loop is not working in solaris (for[i in marks]).

Comment: @jhulan - `declare -A marks` is how you would create an associative array in bash 4, or `typeset -A marks` in zsh or ksh93. Your question and my answer were about doing this in awk, where `set -A marks` would be an error. In awk, all arrays are already associative. If the awk script above doesn't work with the version of awk you're using, could you let me know what version that is and what error it produces?  Happy to help debug, but let's stick to one question (and language) at a time.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR>1 {
    stud = $2
    pct  = $3

    if      ( pct <= 45 ) { band = "THIRD"  }
    else if ( pct <= 60 ) { band = "SECOND" }
    else if ( pct <= 75 ) { band = "FIRST"  }
    else                  { band = "DIST"   }

    pcts[pct][stud]
    bands[band][stud]
}
END {
    for (pct in pcts) {
        out = ""
        for (stud in pcts[pct]) {
            out = (out == "" ? pct "-" : out OFS) stud
        }
        print out
    }

    print "----"

    for (band in bands) {
        out = ""
        for (stud in bands[band]) {
            out = (out == "" ? band ":" : out OFS) stud
        }
        print out
    }
}
```

.

```
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
34-C
42-D,F
75-A,E
77-B,G
----
DIST:B,G
THIRD:C,D,F
FIRST:A,E
```